# Adding Facebook Like button

Tags: html, facebook-like, blogs

I am trying to add facebook like button under my post title. I have tried to put it under

```
<header class='entry-header'>
<b:if cond='data:post.title'>
<h1 class='entry-title' itemprop='name'>
<b:if cond='data:post.link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.link' expr:title='&quot;Permalink to &quot; + data:post.title' rel='bookmark'><data:post.title/></a>
```

above this line of code

```
.post_content { overflow:hidden; }
```

above and below

```
  <data:post.body/>
```

but the facebook like button doesn't appear. If I put it under

```
<header class='entry-header'>
```

before this

```
  <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
```

it appears at the position of post title, which I don't want. Where should I put facebook like button code so that it appears at the notified position

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Maybe you can find something there.

Use HTML5:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sl_SI/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Sir where should I put this code so that it appears under post title

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself. I posted the code right above this code.

```
 <data:post.body/>
```